# How do you create the max and min date in DAX

Tags: excel, dax

I have a date column with dates going from 2016 to 2018. I wanted to create a calculated field in the data model that will output the max date and the min date.

This is the column with the date.

[image]

I want a way to have the max and min date to output on the excel part of the workbook. So basically I want to have a date range in the report.

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Thanks, does this edit answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `MIN` and `MAX` as analytic functions:

```
SELECT
    date,
    -- other columns
    MAX(date) OVER () AS max_date,
    MIN(date) OVER () AS min_date
FROM yourTable;
```

This is speculative, but is correct if what you want is to show the min and max date from all dates as computed columns.